# Partially displaying the Title in the tableView Cell?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

I'm tried to display the Title Data in the Tableview Cell it displayed but partially (...) i want to display full title in the table cell may be in two or three line i used customize cell and use the label and set label property but still data displayed partially

```
 titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
```

Can any one suggest me the way to overcome this prob...

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
myLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
myLabel.numberOfLines = 2; // 2 lines ; 0 - dynamical number of lines
myLabel.text = @"Lorem ipsum dolor sit\namet...";
```

Comment: Aman this will worked but only with hard coded text like   

cell.textLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    cell.textLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    cell.textLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;

but In
 titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
    titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
    titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
BUT THIS give nothing in the tableView cell just blank what should i do...

Comment: had you changed the height of the label, for dynamic data set the numberoflines=0 as mentioned above.

Comment: yes i already changed the height n all an properly set the numberofline to 0 but still the same problem...

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try:

```
[titleLabel sizeToFit];
```

And the you need to adjust the height of the cell with:

```
-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
```

Answer (score 0):

The label's property needs to be set

```
adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
A Boolean value indicating whether the font size should be reduced in order to fit 
the title string into the label’s bounding rectangle.

@property(nonatomic) BOOL adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth
```

And

```
numberOfLines
The maximum number of lines to use for rendering text.

@property(nonatomic) NSInteger numberOfLines
Discussion
This property controls the maximum number of lines to use in order to fit the label’s text into its bounding rectangle. The default value for this property is 1. To remove any maximum limit, and use as many lines as needed, set the value of this property to 0.

If you constrain your text using this property, any text that does not fit within the maximum number of lines and inside the bounding rectangle of the label is truncated using the appropriate line break mode.

When the receiver is resized using the sizeToFit method, resizing takes into account the value stored in this property. For example, if this property is set to 3, the sizeToFit method resizes the receiver so that it is big enough to display three lines of text.
```

Comment: because i used customize cell so i do things with IB i set Attribute Line to 3 , and increase the size of label also by dragging the boundaries but now title is fully hidden only display the three dots (...). Now wht should i do...

Comment: You set the number of lines as 0 and minimum font size .

Answer (score 0):

Hi  try to add label in your cellforRow method

```
CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel *commentsTextLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];;
    commentsTextLabel.tag =50;
    [commentsTextLabel setNumberOfLines:0];
    [commentsTextLabel setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
    NSString *text=[@"dasdasdasdasfasfasfasfasfasfsafasfsafasfasfasfasfsafsafasfasfsaf"];
    [commentsTextLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica"size:14]];
    labelsize=[text sizeWithFont:commentsTextLabel.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    commentsTextLabel.frame=CGRectMake(10, 24, 268, labelsize.height);
    [cell.contentView addSubview:commentsTextLabel];
    [commentsTextLabel release];

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

{
    CGSize labelsize;
    UILabel * textDesc1 = [[UILabel alloc] init];
    [textDesc1 setNumberOfLines:0];
    textDesc1.text=[@"dasdasdasdasfasfasfasfasfasfsafasfsafasfasfasfasfsafsafasfasfsaf"];
    [textDesc1 setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica" size:14.0]];
    labelsize=[textDesc1.text sizeWithFont:textDesc1.font constrainedToSize:CGSizeMake(268, 2000.0) lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeWordWrap];
    labelsize.height=labelsize.height+35;
    [textDesc1 release];
    return (CGFloat)labelsize.height; 


}
```