# Problem in displaying properly in tableView cell by using label

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode4

In my application I parsed the data through NSXMLParser and made separate class to store that data from which i usually display the data. Everything works fine in simulator except the the title which is display in table cell with image. Images appears properly but the title not appear properly.

This is my code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell3" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }
    NewsInfo *aNewsInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
    imageLabel.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;
    return cell;
}
```

and in this way i configured my TableCell3.xib[image: TableCell3.xib]

Now i want my title data in 2 rows in label of the TableCell3.
I already used both the way through xib attributes settings or through code.
Code which i used instead of this xib attributes settings are:-

```
titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
```

Now Can any one help me to figure out this prob i want to display my title in two rows of the table view cell.

Thanks in Advance.

My Data is showing in this way...![enter image description here][2]

So i want to display this title fully it show's partially right now...
i want to display in two lines...

Comment: When you do `titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;` in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`, you mean `cell.titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;` right?

Comment: no man i'm used the customize cell instead of the default one thats why using titlelabel.text not cell.labeltext.text

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the title label isn't being displayed properly? Is it not displaying any text or is it not displaying the text the way you want it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Partially displaying the Title in the tableView Cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184522/partially-displaying-the-title-in-the-tableview-cell)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that you need to enlarge the label height.

Maybe the label height i not large enough to display 2 lines of text and that's could be the reason that you see only 1 line.

in interface builder try to enlarge the label height.

and maybe i am wrong ?

Good luck
Shani

Comment: what is the length of the title? do you want to break a short text line to 2 lines or does your text length is longer then the line width?

Answer (score 0):

Adjust frame of an UiLabel to have more space for two lines or decrease font size.