# Data not display UITableView?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode4

In my application I parsed the data through NSXMLParser and made separate class to store that data from which i usually display the data. Everything works fine in simulator except the the title which is display in table cell with image. Images appears properly but the title not appear properly.

This is my code:-

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

    if (cell == nil) {

        [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"TableCell3" owner:self options:NULL];
        cell = nibLoadedCell;
    }
    NewsInfo *aNewsInfo = [appDelegate.newsArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
    imageLabel.image = aNewsInfo.smallImageData;
    return cell;
}
```

and in this way i configured my TableCell3.xib[image]

Now i want my title data in 2 rows in label of the TableCell3.
I already used both the way through xib attributes settings or through code.
Code which i used instead of this xib attributes settings are:-

```
 titleLabel.lineBreakMode = UILineBreakModeWordWrap;
titleLabel.numberOfLines = 2;
titleLabel.text = aNewsInfo.title;
```

Now Can any one help me to figure out this prob i want to display my title in two rows of the table view cell.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I see that this title label is customly placed in your UITableViewCell. Do you connect the outlets properly so that the value is set to connected uilabel?

Comment: UiLabel is connected properly thats why they showing the data my problem is my title is large sentence but it shows partially i want to display in 2 rows but it not work it shows partially when numberOfLines = 1, but when numberOfLines = 2, it shows nothing just shows (...) what should i do...

Comment: possible duplicate of [Problem in displaying properly in tableView cell by using label.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6192025/problem-in-displaying-properly-in-tableview-cell-by-using-label) and [Partially displaying the Title in the tableView Cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6184522/partially-displaying-the-title-in-the-tableview-cell) Please stop posting the same question repeatedly!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just increase the height of your label and give a try. If the height is too less to hold 2 lines, the label will truncate the contents to 1 line and end with the ellipsis.

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't you be accessing them by

```
cell.titleLabel.text = sometest;
cell.imageLabel.image = someImage;
```

and also ensure that the `titleLabel` and `imageLabel` are connected properly to the outlets. And pls check your naming for the variables. `imageLabel` is not a good choice if you want that to be an imageview.